# android target not installed ошибка cordova windows

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova

Устанавливаю среду разработки на cordova и столкнулся с такой проблемой - при чеке cordova requirements выдает такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

перегуглил, кучу формов но подобной ошибки не нашел подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Опс всё понятно! может кому пригодится - у меня был установлен JDK 11й версии! Стоит ставить JDK 8й, после того как удалил 11й, поставил 8й и прописал set JAVA_HOME по новому - ошибка ушла